# Why does displaying my divs as inline cause them to overlap my h1?

Tags: html, css

I'm just playing around with the border/content box CSS properties in the very early stages of learning.

Trying to make the two boxes line up next to one another- I've achieved it with using the `float` left and right properties.

However, when I use display inline, it causes an overlap with the above block element `h1`. I've displayed it as a table here, so the background colour I've set on it only spans the width of the content, but that shouldn't change the fact that it is still a block element.

More than the overlap, `display: inline` on the `div` causes the boxes to shrink in size as well.

Can anyone explain why this is happening?

Please see the code here: https://jsfiddle.net/gouvrze1/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Only block elements respect width and height rules. Inline elements just flow with their text content. The overlap is caused by the padding and the fact that the divs are further down in the DOM, so they're drawn after and on top of previous elements.

Try changing your divs to `display: inline-block` instead.

Comment: Nvm, just realised they are not side by side due to the whitespace between elements, found a way to clear that. Or use lesser width to account for that missing few %.

Comment: Also, inline elements respect "*line*-height", apparently, so setting that about 55px moves the inline divs down below the heading :D. Thanks providing a solution that also allowed me to look further into the issue :).